# Function to accept nullable type and return nullable type or string

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Basically I want to be able to have one function that takes in a Nullable Type and then returns the value if it has one or the string value "NULL" if it's null so the function needs to be able to take in any nullable type and then return that type or return the string NULL.  Below is kind of what I'm looking for as an example I just can't seem to figure out what I need to do as far as my function.

```
UInt16? a = 5;
UInt16? b = null;
UInt32? c = 10;
UInt32? d = null;

Console.WriteLine(MyFunction<UInt16?>(a)) // Writes 5 as UInt16?
Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(UInt16?>(b)) // Writes NULL as String
Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(UInt32?>(c)) // Writes 10 as UInt32?
Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(UInt32?>(d)) // Writes NULL as String

static T MyFunction<T>(T arg)
{
    String strNULL = "NULL";

    if (arg.HasValue)
        return arg;
    else
        return strNULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static string MyFunction<T>(Nullable<T> arg) where T : struct
{
    String strNULL = "NULL";

    if (arg.HasValue)
        return arg.Value.ToString();
    else
        return strNULL;
}
```

Comment: Of course, the value of returning "NULL" as a string is debatable. If you're going to still have to deal with what to do when it's null, you're not gaining anything by moving the logic into a method.

Comment: @DanielMann that's just an answer to particular problem described in the question. It's OP idea to return "NULL"

Comment: This won't compile as is: `T` needs to be a non-nullable type to be valid in `Nullable<T>` (i.e. with `where T : struct`)

Comment: @empi I know, I'm just pointing out something that the individual who asked the question may not have considered, which may point them to an entirely different approach to their problem.

Comment: @DanielMann It sounds suspiciously like homework, so I doubt that it really matters.

Comment: That works in my the case I'm actually using it in however I really preferred to return the datatype it is when it's not null and return the string value "NULL" when it is null.  No it's not homework.  It's a small console app that reads in a text file and creates various SQL statements for populating a database.  Values that are missing from the import file are kept as NULL data types and that needs to be converted to the string value "NULL" so this was my attempt to return the value if not null or "NULL" when it is null.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer although not 100% what I was looking for it does get the job done.  Further it ended up being a data issue from the customer that caused me to need this to begin with so they are correcting the data and this become mute.